# How can I insert SQL sentence with String instance?

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

[image]

It my code to insert (Id, score) to DB
name[] is name [65,65,65] to convert ASCii to char.
and tabel setting is var(3),int

that code shows me pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'ZBZ' in 'field list'") error

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the code as text instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code fails because you aren't quoting the name.  All strings need to be quoted. You should let the database connector do this; it knows the rules and how to prevent SQL injection attacks.

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO Normal (id, score) VALUES (?,?);'
cursor.execute(sql, (name2, score))
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, ThankU, I change ?,? to %s,%s It works well